# How to compare between an array string element and set string element in java

Tags: java, arrays, set

Here I need to compare the elements present in a Set with the elements in an array.

```
   `System.out.println("Enter Student's Article");
    sentence=sc.nextLine();
    lowerCase(sentence);
    String [] array=sentence.split("[ ,;:.?!]+");
    System.out.println("Number of words "+array.length);
    Set <String> set=new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(array));
    //System.out.println(set.size());
    for(String str:set){
        count=0;
        for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++){
            if(str==array[j])
                count++;
                System.out.println(count);
        }
        System.out.println(str+":"+count);
    }
}`
```

The logic behind my code is:
I received an input sentence and I converted it into lowercase.
Then I split each word based on some characters as mentioned in the code and store each splitted word to array.
Now I convert it into a set.
Now I need to count the frequency of each element in the set with repsect to the array.

For example
If I give input as
"hi hi hi hello"
I would get
Number of words 4
hi:3
hello:1

So please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try the code below and compare the changes with your original code
```

```
     Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
     String sentence=sc.nextLine();
     sentence.toLowerCase();
     String [] array=sentence.split("[ ,;:.?!]+");
     System.out.println("Number of words "+array.length);
     Set <String> set=new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(array));
     //System.out.println(set.size());
     for(String str:set){
         int count=0;
         for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++){
             if(str.equals(array[j]))
                 count++;
                 //System.out.println(count);
         }
         System.out.println(str+":"+count);
     }
```

Comment: thanks.....Now if i give input for example `hello Hello HEllo hi! hi Welcome,welcome`       output is obtained as hi:2 hello:3 welcome:2  but i need it has  **hello:3 hi:2 welcome:2**

Comment: i think the elemnts in the set is [hi,hello,welcome]   can we rearrange it as [hello,hi,welcome]

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code count the frequency of each element.

```
    Map<String , Integer> dictionary=new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    String myWords = "soon hi also soon job mother job also soon later";
    myWords = myWords.toLowerCase();
    String[] array=myWords.split("\\s+");
    for(String s:array){
        if(dictionary.containsKey(s))
            dictionary.put(s, dictionary.get(s)+1);
        else
            dictionary.put(s, 1);
    }
    System.out.println("Number of words "+myWords.length());
    for (String key : dictionary.keySet()) {
        System.out.print(key +":"+ dictionary.get(key));
    }
```

Comment: I am new to Map .so i didnt go for this approach.let me check this too..Thanks